# Magento no emails send from magento fresh installation

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cron, order-email

I am using `magento 1.9.2` It not sending order and other emails from the system. I setup in the following way,

**Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System**

[image]

**Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails**
[image]

Like the same way same settings for all sales emails.

After this I set a cron job on my cpanel to send every 5 mints.

**Cpanel Cron Job**

[image]

These settings all done. But no emails send. Do I need any other settings ? How can I send emails ?

Comment: Did you try simple mail function check mail is going or not

Comment: check mail and magento logs

Comment: @MagenX Email is not getting. which log file is to be checked ?

Comment: magento: `/home/?/public_html/var/log/*`   mail: `/var/log/exim_mainlog`  or `/var/log/exim_rejectlog`  cron log: `/var/log/cron`

Comment: @MagenX on var/log folder only two files exception.log and system.log